# Adding missing subtraction and division operators to sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to implement step by step math solver in sympy. Arithmetic operators +, -, *, /, ** are mapped to combinations of three core SymPy’s classes: Add, Mul and Pow. 
However I need a substraction and division in expression tree so that I can print it while stepping through. I know that I need to change or at least override some behavior in sympy but I dont know where and how?
Any idea on this? Thanks.

Comment: Modifying SymPy to use subtraction and division operators in its expression tree sounds like a major undertaking. There may be some easier ways to get what you want. Can you provide more details on what you might provide as an input and what you might expect as an output?

Comment: @butterwagon thank you for response. For example, for the input (sqrt(9)-1)/2), I should print something like:                                                                                     (step 1). Calculate the root of 9                                                                                        
(step 2). Substract 1 from 3                                                                                              
(step 3). Divide 2 by 2